# How to get image in real-time?

Tags: rendering, performance

It doesn't matter if it works like a capture or if the quality is very low. There's no reason for shadows or light, too. I hope to get only materials' color and shape of model. Just i want real-time. How can i do?

Comment: Hi! Please take your time and try to explain in *detail* what you'd like to achieve. Not sure what you're asking for... realtime of what exaclty? Please read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

In Blender there are 4 view modes, they are placed on the top right part of the viewport,  from left to right it's: wireframe, solid, material, and rendered view. I think the material view (the 3rd one from the left) is the one you're looking for.

[image]